# Split frontend and servlet mapping into different modules

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, jsf-2.2

I am currently refactoring a web application that has been around for 13 years. First I updated the dependencies to Java SE 8, Tomcat 7 and JSF 2.2. The next task in the refactoring process is to split the functionalities and the respective frontends into seperate modules.

My goal is that each seperate module, that has a frontend, is responsible for its own routing and servlet mapping. The "Core"-module should direct the traffic to the respective module and let the module serve the desired content.

And that's where I'm facing immense trouble.

An approach to the problem was the following tutorial (in german): https://www.tutorials.de/threads/modularisierbare-web-anwendungen-mit-jee6-web-profile-web-fragments.372772/, which is about web-fragments (web.xml files in modules) that can easily be included in a parent web.xml.
**However the core module can't reach the desired files, and I just can't figure out why.**

Please take a look at the following files:

pom.xml (excerpt of module 1 (core)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-frontendmodul</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml (excerpt of module 1 (core) web.xml):

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd" metadata-
     complete="false">
[...]
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
[...]
```

Since we just now started the refactoring, a part of the core module is a web app.

The folder structure to the respective files (module 1 (core)):

- src.main

  - java
  - resources
  - webapp

    - newpages

      - (all views currently are in here)
    - WEB-INF

      - web.xml

Folder structure to respective files (module 2):

- src.main

  - java
  - resources

    - META-INF

      - web.xml
  - webapp

    - pages

      - AktuelleSchritteAlle.xhtml

pom.xml (module 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <parent>
       <artifactId>myapp-production</artifactId>
       <groupId>org.myapp</groupId>
       <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <name>My App - Frontend Modul</name>
   <artifactId>myapp-frontendmodul</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

web.xml (module 2):

```
<web-fragment xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
    id="myapp-frontendmodul">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-fragment>
```

AktuelleSchritteAlle.xhtml (module 2):

```
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
>
    <f:view locale="de">
        <h:body>
            <h:outputText>test</h:outputText>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it work in a newer version of Tomcat? And btw, tomcat is not java-ee, so that is a contradictory in tags...

Comment: I've already tried it with Tomcat 8 and it doesn't work as well. Unfortunately i'm forced to use Tomcat 7 @Kukeltje

Comment: Start by comparing your 'core' web-app.xml to the one in the tutorial. Major version difference! And _However the core module can't reach the desired files, and I just can't figure out why._ is totally unclear. Please specify and state what you debugged etc...

Comment: Thank you! I changed the version, but it still doesn't work. Regarding what I debugged: I don't even know what URL I need to use to access the AktuelleSchritteAlle.jsf. When I open a view that lays in the core module I need to use e.g. http://localhost:8080/myapp/newpages/AktuelleProzesse.jsf.

Comment: You are lucky my German is (almost) as good as my English and Dutch. Read the tutorial again, but read it good. Many differences between your setup, config, file locations and the ones in the tutorial (also most likely differences in the module pom which you did not post)